# Add coordinates to dataframe to display an image with osm background

Tags: python, pandas, background, openstreetmap

I'm working with temperature data from tif images. I already did a lot of working computing those images with dataframes. [image: I have 100+ images like this with the same coordinates.]

I have 100+ images like this with the same coordinates.
I just realized that I need to georeferenzed the images to be able to display the background with OSM.

I have this code, to get the bbox of my image :

```
path= '/mnt/Data/30_Stages_Encours/2023/ZonesHumides_Sarah/image_traitee/modis/2017/MOD/K_MOD11A1_061_LST_Day_1km_doy2017014_aid0001.tif'
ds = gdal.Open(path)
width = ds.RasterXSize
height = ds.RasterYSize
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
minx = gt[0]
miny = gt[3] + width*gt[4] + height*gt[5] 
maxx = gt[0] + width*gt[1] + height*gt[2]
maxy = gt[3] 

COORD_4326 = ((maxy,minx), (maxy,maxx), (miny,maxx),(miny,minx))

from shapely.geometry import Polygon
geometry = Polygon(COORD_4326)
```

Now that I have the geometry of my image, I want to plot my dataframe with this geometry. I know that I can use GeoPandas.